# Reading a file to char array then malloc size. (C)

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, command-line-arguments

Hey, so lets say I get a file as the first command line argument.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    unsigned char* fileArray;

    FILE* file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
}
```

Now how can I go about reading that file, char by char, into the `char* fileArray`?

Basically how can I convert a `FILE*` to a `char*` before I know how big I need to malloc the `char*`

I know a possible solution is to use a buffer, but my problem here is I'm dealing with files that could have over 900000 chars, and don't see it fit making a buffer that is that large.

Comment: you mean you don't want characters in continuos memory location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only "real" files (not stream, devices, ...) are used, you can use `stat`/`fstat` or something like

```
int retval=fseek(file1,0,SEEK_END); // succeeded if ==0  (file seekable, etc.)
long size=ftell(file1); // size==-1 would be error
rewind(file1);
```

to get the file's size beforehand. Then you can malloc and read.
But since file1 might change in the meantime you still have to ensure not to read beyond your malloced size.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches you can take:

- specify a maximum size that you can handle, then you just allocate once (whether as a global or on the heap).
- handle the file in chunks if you're worried about fitting it all into memory at once.
- handle an arbitrary size by using `malloc` with `realloc` (as you read bits in).

Number 1 is easy:

```
static char buff[900001];                  // or malloc/free of 900000
count = fread (buff, 1, 900001, fIn);
if (count > 900000)                        // problem!
```

Number 2 is probably the best way to do it unless you absolutely *need* the whole file in memory at once. For example, if your program counts the number of words, it can sequentially process the file a few K at a time.

Number 3, you can maintain a `buffer`, `used` and `max` variable. Initially set `max` to 50K and allocate `buffer` as that size.

Then try read in one 10K chunk to a fixed buffer `tbuff`. Add up the current `used` and the number of bytes read into `tbuff` and, if that's greater than `max`, do a `realloc` to increase `buffer` by another 50K (adjusting `max` at the same time).

Then append `tbuff` to `buffer`, adjust `used`, rinse and repeat. Note that all those values (10K, 50K and so on) are examples only. There are different values you can use depending on your needs.